# servlet 3.0, node.js, concurrent approach

Tags: node.js, concurrency, servlet-3.0

what is the best approach: servlet 3.0 or node.js?

i'm thinking in a high concurrent application's architecture that use some of the most modern technologies.

i'm divided between servlet3 and node.js. i'm thinking in develop an auction system for a local (niche) market.

are there some comparison evolving these technologies? still better: has anyone here tested these approaches in a (high) concurrent application?

thanks in advance.

Comment: interesting blog post: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19577

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about nodeJS but non-typesafe code with a poor resemblance to object oriented programming on the server-side scares the hell out of me... That's not a place for js in my opinion.
Servlet 3.0 solved many of the performance issues the servlet implementations previously had so I think it would be whole lot safer to go on with java.

Comment: +1 I totally agree that JS does not belong to server side unless for a very limited purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Servlet, but just look at some real-life Node.js in action:
Videos:
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongonyc-2011/mongodb-and-nodejs
http://blip.tv/jsconfeu/by-philip-hofstetter-node-js-in-production-use-tempalias-com-4258344
http://joyeur.com/2011/08/11/node-js-meetup-distributed-web-architectures/
Articles:
http://debuggable.com/posts/parsing-file-uploads-at-500-mb-s-with-node-js:4c03862e-351c-4faa-bb67-4365cbdd56cb
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/07/multicore_http_server_with_nodejs/
http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/
http://corp.klout.com/blog/2011/10/the-tech-behind-klout-com/
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2011/09/13.html

Projects, Applications, and Companies Using Node
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

Answer (score 0):

Node.js cannot perform well in case of CPU bound computations.

Comment: That's a non-issue. Any CPU bound computations would be done in C and exposed to node.js. The same applies to Java, any real CPU bound computation shouldn't be done in Java.

Comment: *any real CPU bound computation shouldn't be done in Java* this is an overstatement, what do you prefer - hand optimized assembler?

Comment: Without a reasonable attempt at linking to a balanced benchmark this is just trolling.